# Combining facet and stats results from three Solr queries

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I have two solr queries one is faceted and another one is a stats query over a same parameter.  I would like to combine results from both queries in Solr.

Imagine a game database, we want to get statistics for all games. Game session doc has fields

game_id, user_id, country, play_time, completion_rate

Here are example of those queries

**Total unique plays for games from USA**
q=*:*&facet=true&facet.pivot=game_id,user_id&fq=country:USA

Result:

```
GAMEID  |  TOTAL_UNIQUE_PLAYS
   1    |       10
   2    |       15
```

**Average played time for games from USA**

q=*:*&stats=true&stats.facet=game_id&stats.field=play_time&fq=country:USA

```
 Result:
    GAMEID    |   AVG_PLAYTIME
       1      |       100
       2      |       150
```

**Average completion rate games from USA**

q=*:*&stats=true&stats.facet=game_id&stats.field=completion_rate&fq=country:USA

```
Result:
GAMEID    |   AVG_COMPLETION_RATE
   1      |       50
   2      |       100
```

I would like to combine all 3 results as following

```
   GAMEID   |   TOTAL_UNIQUE_PLAYS   |   AVG_PLAYTIME   | AVG_COMPLETION_RATE
       1    |       100              |         10       |         50
       2    |       150              |         15       |         100
```

How can I do this in Solr and if I would like to add more queries to it ?

Comment: Hi, can you please share some sample data so that I can reproduce these individual queries

Comment: The JSON Facet API should be able to solve this for you again; did you try to extend the previous example? I.e. create a gameid bucket on the lowest level, then avg(completion_rate), avg(playtime) and count/unique(field) for each facet on the second level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON Facet API will let you add multiple aggregations under a bucket:

```json
{
  "query": "*:*",
  "facet": {
    "categories":{
      "type": "terms",
      "field": "GAMEID",
      "limit": 20,
      "facet": {
        "total_unique_players": "unique(user_id)",
        "avg_playtime": "avg(playtime)",
        "avg_completion_rate": "avg(completion_rate)",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The aggregation functions should then be applied for each unique term in `GAMEID`, giving you the averages and unique count per game.